# How do I add a Safari icon to my website?

Tags: html, css, safari

As seen here - https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH4S9.jpg

I have several websites with icons. My personal website however, is just the first letter of the website.

How do I add an icon that will appear in Safari favorites? The Favicon doesn't display here as I had originally thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put an icon to your browser (called `favicon`) with this in your `<head>`:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"/>
```

and for apple:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="touch-icon-iphone.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="touch-icon-ipad.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="touch-icon-iphone-retina.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="touch-icon-ipad-retina.png">
```

Read this article if you want to know more about it: https://css-tricks.com/favicon-quiz/

Remember that Icons take a long time to update so you'll need to wait a bit.

Comment: Thanks, do I add this to my <head> of the the site? </head>

Comment: Yes, in the <head> tag. Check this site: http://realfavicongenerator.net/

Comment: Okay, it still doesn't seem to be working for some reason. I've added the following lines:      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/clipshout-production/csicon.png">
     <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/clipshout-production/csicon.png"/>
  </head>

Comment: It just has the letter C with no icon :(, any ideas?

Comment: @AnthonyPinto Favicon and Icon in general take **A LONG TIME** to update so just wait a bit.

Comment: It's not the Favicon I'm looking to update it's the Safari facorites icon as seen here: http://imgur.com/a/HJQr8

Comment: Same, try with another device

Comment: it should be ok

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the apple-touch-icon like in the example below:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/custom_icon.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert this in your head:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://cdn.css-tricks.com/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://cdn.css-tricks.com/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://cdn.css-tricks.com/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
```

just replace the links with your fav-icon at that size, so it looks nice and not blurry

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately, I'm trying to update this http://imgur.com/a/HJQr8 .. Any ideas? does the file have to be a certain type, e.g. not Png?

Comment: Yes it must be a png

Comment: Is it rel="icon" or rel="apple-touch-icon"

Comment: Its meant to be icon

Comment: Ok i made added both.. still not working, any ideas?  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/clipshout-production/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/clipshout-production/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png" sizes="16x16">